# google_images_download module not downloading images

Tags: python-3.6

When I use the following code I found online, as well as the example code shown by the creator on pypi, all that shows up is "Unfortunately all 4 could not be downloaded because some images were not downloadable. 0 is all we got for this search filter!". For the code below, many other people on the site were having problems with it, but I couldn't find any fixes or explanations. I'm not sure why it's not downloading, because I left the search terms broad.

```
response = google_images_download.googleimagesdownload()

search_queries = ["kittens","kitten"]

def downloadimages(query): 
    arguments = {"keywords": query, 
                 "format": "jpg", 
                 "limit":4, 
                 "print_urls":True, 
                 "size": "medium", 
                 "aspect_ratio":"square"} 
    try: 
        response.download(arguments)
    except FileNotFoundError:  
        arguments = {"keywords": query, 
                     "format": "jpg", 
                     "limit":4, 
                     "print_urls":True, 
                     "size": "medium", 
                     "aspect_ratio":"square"} 
        try: 
            response.download(arguments)  
        except: 
            pass
for query in search_queries: 
    downloadimages(query)  
    print()
```